# JavaFX - Check if Application is on foreground

Tags: java, javafx, focus, visible, stage

I am actually developing a Chat application.
If the user recevies a new message i send a notification to his desktop, even if he has the program on foreground. That is pretty annoying.
So i'd like to know how to check if the application is on foerground/focused/showing (whatever).
I have already googled but didnt find a way that works.

Comment: I don't know of a robust Java mechanism for this.  I think you'll need to use OS-level libraries (IE: [Windows Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: @Ironcache I am using Java, i can not use the windows libaries right? Anyways Java programs are supposed to be crossplatform and not windows specific(mine is) :)

Comment: To your first point, no, Java programs can interact with native libraries.  Take a look into [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access).  To your second point, what can I say?  The functionality is not available in a robust manner in Java AFAIK.  If you want a cross-platform app, you need to work with the native libraries of the platforms you're targetting, or accept this as a downside.  You can try `isFocused()` and `isShowing()` in the [Window](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html) class, but I don't think it'll prove satisfactory.

Comment: @Ironcache My colleague just tried it with a blank application and it works with the focusedProperty, with my application it doesn't. the change listener on the focusedProperty doesn't even get called and isFocused also returns false permanently

Comment: Yep, focus is fickle and relying on it outside of the context of what has focus **within Java** is often dubious, in my experience.  Java's focus mechanics don't work well when going outside Java.  That said, attempting to get your colleagues results to be the same as yours, I have a couple questions: 1) How is he minimizing vs. how are you minimizing.  Pressing minimize vs. selecting a different window (outside the current JVM) are different from Java's point of view. 2) What OS is he running on vs. you?  Are you able to reproduce the results of his blank application on your machine?

Comment: That said `isFocused()` and `focused` should not be false if the window is the active OS window...  That functionality should certainly work.  What are you checking the `focusedProperty()` of?  The window itself?

Comment: @Ironcache i did check the stages property, anyways now it works, idon't even know what i changed xD.But i have found quite a great libary  a while ago that may help, it is a low level systemhook for mouse and keyboard:
https://github.com/kristian/system-hook

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late but I hope it can help someone

```
primaryStage.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if(!newValue) {
                // if windows doesn't focused
                // do action
            }
        }
});
```

To directly verify that the window is focused, do this

```
if(!primaryStage.isFocused()) {
    // if windows doesn't focused
    // do action
}
```